# PHP - CategoryDropdown::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args)

Tags: php, wordpress

Classpress installed on my wordpress hosting and this with the following error , already looked at the code as a whole and to the moemnto nothing, understand where change to eliminate the error.

> CategoryDropdown::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) should
>   be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0,
>   $args = Array, $current_object_id = 0) in
>   /home/u785732335/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/classipress/includes/theme-functions.php
>   on line 1410

```
// needed for the cp_category_dropdown_tree function
class cp_CategoryDropdown extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');
    function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
        $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->term_id."\">";
        $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
        $output .= ' - ' . get_option('cp_curr_symbol') . get_option('cp_cat_price_'.$category->cat_ID) . '</option>'."\n";;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `$current_object_id` argument to the `start_el()` function. Try changing the code to look like this...

```
// needed for the cp_category_dropdown_tree function
class cp_CategoryDropdown extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');
    function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args, $current_object_id = 0) {
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
        $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->term_id."\">";
        $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
        $output .= ' - ' . get_option('cp_curr_symbol') . get_option('cp_cat_price_'.$category->cat_ID) . '</option>'."\n";;
    }
}
```